# Prevent RecyclerView loading from delaying transition

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-transitions

I have two activities A and B. A contains a RecyclerView and a click on an item of that RecyclerView starts activity B which also contains a RecyclerView.
This my enter transition for the whole app:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:transitionOrdering="sequential">
<slide android:slideEdge="end">
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
    </targets>
</slide>
```

and this is the exit transition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<slide android:slideEdge="start">
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
    </targets>
</slide>
```

The start of activity B freezes for some milliseconds due to the recyclerview set up and fetching data from firebase to populate it.
Is there a way to start the transition immediately? I mean, is there a way to prevent the recyclerview from delaying the transition?